# DropDownListFor throws exception when user didn't select any value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I got an exception when user submitted a form without selecting any value in the `dropdownlistfor` as follows:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.TypeID,
            new SelectList(ViewBag.EventType, "ID", "Name"),
            "-- Select Event Type --"
            )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
    </div>
```

I got an exception:

> *Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items*

I think I have to check if user selected a value or make an alert, but I'm not sure how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a nullable type for the `TypeID` property on your view model if you want to handle the non-selected case in your drop down list (`"-- Select Event Type --"`):

```
public int? TypeID { get; set; }
```

You are getting the exception because if the user doesn't select any option in the dropdown, the default one is used:

```
<option value="">"-- Select Event Type --"</option>
```

Notice how the value is empty string. This obviously cannot be bound to a non-nullable integer  type on your model.